# What size is a division?

Tags: meaning

At my university, located in Sweden, the *division of X* is a sub-part of the *department of Y*. My colleague, a native speaker, claims that this is entirely wrong; he says *divisions* should be the *largest* unit.

Is a *division* normally a smaller unit than a *department*, a larger unit, or can it be either way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: there is no uniform convention even within American English for those two words, and I suspect within other dialects there isn't, either. Your friend is correct, so far as the US Government goes, but really, it stops there. In my US-based corporation founded almost entirely by Americans and those who have learned American English, it is exactly the opposite. We have big divisions (US, Europe, Asia) and smaller departments (Human Resources for the US division).

There are some general patterns, though. For example, in the US, an *office* will be a smaller unit than a *bureau* (even though bureau is the French word for *office*. Again, this is a pattern, and not a rule.

Even in the US Government, the FBI (Federal Bureau of Investigation) is part of the Department of Homeland Security and has within it both offices and divisions, and divisions of offices, and offices inside divisions. In this sort of usage, offices probably have more specific tasks than divisions, which probably group tasks together... but really, it's the government, so one only expects so much "rhyme or reason" in its organization.

Answer (score 8):

As far I know, division does not necessarily need to be directly below the largest unit. It's really up to the person who designed the system.

Comment: In military there's first the army, then the corps, then the division.

Answer (score 3):

Well to start with let's think about the root of the word: if you have a division, that means something was *divided*.  So literally, what you said is exactly correct: a division is anything which is a sub-part of something else.

As to the size of a division in practice, I really don't think there are any rules for that.  You can call it a division, a group, a department, a section...  There are any number of appropriate terms that could have been used for the divisions at your university.  It just depends on the person who named it.  The important thing is just that an entire organization as a whole cannot be a division; ie. the university itself cannot be a division because it is a whole.  A division is a piece of a whole, not the entire thing.

Answer (score 0):

This naming concept is different in different places. Generally, you would have a division in a department, with division being the smaller group.

It is up to the system designer however.

Comment: But at the university I attended, it was the "Division of Engineering" (now the "School of Engineering"), and it was considered to be on a higher level than a department.  "Different in different places" is a good characterization.

Comment: In this case it was the University that was *divided* into *divisions*. In the OP's case, it was the Derpartment that was divided.